# JavaScript Finding if string in array can be found in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach, indexof

I have an object that includes different roles and I have an array that includes specific colors.

What I want to do, is see if the roles.name includes any of the strings in the colors array. I've tried different approaches, such as:

```
var colors = ["blue", "yellow", "brown", "red", "green", "pink", "purple"];
var roles = [{"name": "asd"},
            {"name": "blue"},
            {"name": "yellow"},
            {"name": "brown"}, 
            {"name": "red"},
            {"name": "green"},
            {"name": "pink"},
            {"name": "purple"},
            {"name": "fgh"},
            {"name": "jkl"}];
for (var i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
    if (roles[i].name.indexOf(colors)) {
   console.log(roles[i].name);
  }
}
```

And

```
var colors = ["blue", "yellow", "brown", "red", "green", "pink", "purple"];
var roles = [{"name": "asd"},
            {"name": "blue"},
            {"name": "yellow"},
            {"name": "brown"}, 
            {"name": "red"},
            {"name": "green"},
            {"name": "pink"},
            {"name": "purple"},
            {"name": "fgh"},
            {"name": "jkl"}];
roles.forEach(role => {
    if (role.name.indexOf(colors)) {
    console.log(role.name);
  }
});
```

But with both of the codes, the result is the full list of roles.

Expected result is all colors logged to the console. What I get is all roles logged to the console.

Comment: In ES6 you can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), there is also [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Your object has all the keys with the same name, literally, they're all called `name`, so you overwrite the previous keys and values.

Comment: How are all the roles being logged when you're treating an object like an array?

Comment: The var roles is incorrect and is not in fact like that. I made a mistake in that part. They're all actually separate objects. I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `indexOf` backwards. It should be `array.indexOf(valueToSearchFor)`, but you have `valueToSearchFor.indexOf(array)`. Also, `indexOf` returns the index, not a boolean; to test whether the element is found, you have to compare it to `-1`.

```js
var colors = ["blue", "yellow", "brown", "red", "green", "pink", "purple"];
var roles = [{"name": "asd"},
        {"name": "blue"},
        {"name": "yellow"},
        {"name": "brown"}, 
        {"name": "red"},
        {"name": "green"},
        {"name": "pink"},
        {"name": "purple"},
        {"name": "fgh"},
        {"name": "jkl"}];
for (var i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
  if (colors.indexOf(roles[i].name) != -1) {
    console.log(roles[i].name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I actually tried this approach but without the != -1. Didn't know it wouldn't return a boolean. Thank you.

Comment: There's no excuse for that mistake. I'll bet every tutorial on using `indexOf` explains it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var colors = ["blue", "yellow", "brown", "red", "green", "pink", "purple"];
var roles = [{"name": "asd"}, {"name": "blue"}, {"name": "yellow"}, {"name": "brown"},{"name": "red"}, {"name": "green"}, {"name": "pink"}, {"name": "purple"}, {"name": "fgh"}, {"name": "jkl"}];
var discovered = [];
for (var i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
   for (var j=0 ; j < colors.length ; j++){
     if (roles[i].name == colors[j]) {
        discovered.push(roles[i]);
     }
   }
}

console.log(discovered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your roles is only an Object. Prefer this format.

```
    let colors = [
    {
        "name": "blue"
    },
    {
        "name": "yellow"
    },
    {
        "name": "brown"
    },
    {
        "name": "red"
    },
    {
        "name": "green"
    },
    {
        "name": "pink"
    },
    {
        "name": "purple"
    }
]
```

And It's each color with using `.map()`

```
colors.map(function (color) {
    console.log(color.name)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You switched out role and colors when calling `indexOf`.
And ´indexOf´ doesnt return a ´boolean´ but an integer and if it returns `0` it would evaluate to ´false ´to which will cause wrong results.

```
roles.forEach(function (role) {
  if (colors.indexOf(role.name) >= 0) {
    console.log(role.name);
  }
});
```